# How to change a certain value in a hundreds of tables into NaN in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I got a hundred of files, in which all the NaN is mistakenly written as 'N.A.'. I need to correct all the file in order to do calculations in Matlab. I wrote some codes as below but it always complained an error. I tried N.A. with and without quotes in the code, but still error. Could somebody help? I really have no idea where the code is wrong.

```
Data = dir('*.xls');
namelist1={Data.name};
for w = 1: numel(Data)
    basefilenamedata=Data(w).name;
    T=readtable(basefilenamedata);
    P=table2array(T);
    P(P ==N.A.) = NaN; % here I also tried P(P =='N.A.') = NaN, but still an error
    W=array2table(P);
    writetable(W,fullfile(DataFolder,[basefilenamedata '.xls']),'Sheet',1,'Range','A1');
end

Error: File: untitled Line: 7 Column: 15
Unbalanced or unexpected parenthesis or bracket.
```

File example 1:

```
colony  center_y    center_x    radii   area
1   1486.035197 1994.842984 52  8494.866535
2   1839.73197  439.5529361 58  10568.31769
3   1173.664471 403.4185646 64  12867.96351
4   N.A.    N.A.    N.A.    N.A.
5   N.A.    N.A.    N.A.    N.A.
```

File example 2:

```
Area    Centroid_1  Centroid_2  MeanGrey    ColonyNum
12984   868.0061614 340.6169901 61  1
12378   1289.909517 253.0196316 67  2
N.A.    N.A.    N.A.    N.A.    3
```

Comment: Why not just replace `N.A.` with `NaN`? Isn't that what you want? This is easy in a decent text editor like Notepad++ or Sublime Text.

Comment: @EdCottrell yeah, to replace `N.A.` with `NA` is exactly what I want. But I don't know how to do it quickly, as I have more than 100 excel files to correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at `standardizeMissing`

```
T0 = readtable(basefilenamedata);
T = standardizeMissing(T0 ,{Inf,'N/A','N.A.'},'DataVariables',{'a','x'}) %change to your data variables name
```

Second thing, to compare strings in matlab u should use `strcmp` and not `==`.

Third thing, you can see how a table should look like, run `open('patients.xls')` in command line.

Comment: Thanks Mendi! It's super! I modified a bit your code, as my tables have different variable names in different table. I changed the second line of your code to this `T = standardizeMissing(T0 ,{Inf,'N/A','N.A.'});` and it works! Thank you!

Comment: Sorry it's me again. I found that when I use the code mentioned above, I will sendup with all the numbers stored as text in excel files. Then it cause me problem to do the late calculations. Do you know why will the numbers be stored as text?

Comment: Look at readtable help. You can specify the format : readtable(filename,'Format','%s%s%u%f%f%s')

Answer (score 1):

A find-replace in your excel files would quickly fix this problem. Anyway, if you want to solve it programmatically, I will explain you first what's happening.

The function `readtable` tries to heuristically define the type of your table columns, calling `detectImportOptions` internally, before parsing them. If it finds strings (different than the ones commonly used to represent a true `NaN`, like, in this example, `N.A.`) coupled with numbers, it may decide to interpret that specific column as a column of string values.

To overcome this problem, call `detectImportOptions`, modify the `VariableTypes` parameter "manually", and pass it to the `readtable` function.

```
for w = 1: numel(Data)
    basefilenamedata = Data(w).name;
    opts = detectImportOptions(basefilenamedata);

    % Make sure that your P column type is set as double...
    opts = setvartype(opts,{'double' 'double' 'double' ...});

    T = readtable(basefilenamedata,opts);

    % Go on writing...
end
```

If the files are all identical, you can also perform this only once with the first file, outside your loop, and then pass the same `opts` to all your `readtable` calls.

This approach will be much, much faster than sanitizing your input, sanitizing your data once it's parsed and all such approaches... especially if you can work with a single option for all your files.

Comment: Thanks Tommaso! Now I understand why it didn't work. But what about every table is not really the same, even the number of columns are not the same?